# Keywords that can be used as variable name

Tags: javascript

In some JavaScript editors, `of`, `async`, `await`, `let`, `yield`, etc are considered keywords, but using those words as variable or function names work, and no errors occur. Are those really keywords, or is it recommended to use as variables?

Comment: "In some JavaScript editors...", I'd like to clarify that this is actually stated in the ECMAScript specification, and they are indeed keywords. However, they are allowed to be used as variable names for the sake of backwards compatibility with ECMAScript 5 and prior versions.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_word_usage